# How to manage data on concurrent Http Triggered Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have the following code in my Azure Function:

```
string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
myObject.id = id;
```

Now, if I make multiple http calls at the same time, concurrent calls are ending up having the same id, I am expecting them to have different id.

I have tried changing host.json, but no luck. anyways here's the code in host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Azure Function Version: 2
Dotnet version: 5.0

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: For reference, please provide us with information like the version of .NET, Azure Functions and the OS you're running on. Also. sharing all _relevant_ code would help.

Comment: If you place the code that creates a new GUID inside the body of the azure function, there's no way to the returned value be the same. You should post the entire code of your azure function so we can help you in an efficient way. Probably you are doing some mistake like placing the instantiation of the Guid in a static context, so in this case the function will be executed once and you will get always the same result. Azure handles correctly concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [Guid.NewGuid Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid) documentation.

> This is a convenient static method that you can call to get a new Guid. The method creates a Version 4 Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) as described in RFC 4122, Sec. 4.4. The returned Guid is guaranteed to not equal Guid.Empty.
>
> On Windows, this function wraps a call to the CoCreateGuid function. The generated GUID contains 122 bits of strong entropy.
>
> On non-Windows platforms, starting with .NET 6, this function calls the OS's underlying cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator (CSPRNG) to generate 122 bits of strong entropy. In previous versions of .NET, the entropy is not guaranteed to be generated by a CSPRNG.

The RFC that is being referred to states:

> The version 4 UUID is meant for generating UUIDs from truly-random or pseudo-random numbers.
>
> The algorithm is as follows:
>
> - Set the two most significant bits (bits 6 and 7) of the `clock_seq_hi_and_reserved` to zero and one, respectively.
> - Set the four most significant bits (bits 12 through 15) of the `time_hi_and_version` field to the 4-bit version number from Section 4.1.3.
> - Set all the other bits to randomly (or pseudo-randomly) chosen values.

Based on these specifications, getting two calls to the same Azure Function generate the same GUID should be impossible. Some local testing shows that it is (in a testable amount of requests) impossible.

Chances are you have a static property or object somewhere which is the reason for your equal ids.